# Get all properties from an object including properties of reference members

Tags: c#, reflection

Example:

```
 public class B
    {
        [IsSearchable]
        [IsEncryptable]
        public string bPropA { get; set; }
        [IsSearchable]
        [IsEncryptable]
        public string bPropB { get; set; }
    }
    class A
    {
        [IsSearchable]
        [IsEncryptable]
        public string PropA { get; set; }
        [IsSearchable]
        [IsEncryptable]
        public string PropB { get; set; }
        [IsSearchable]
        public int PropC { get; set; }
        [IsSearchable]
        public B PropD { get; set; }
    }
```

So out of the example above I want all 6 properties when sending an object of class A to a function.
So far I've tried:

```
    A a = new A();
    a.GetType().GetAllProperties();
```

But it only returns the 4 properties and not it's members properties.
Looked around but couldn't find any question regarding this matter at least not specifically.

Comment: You'd have to recursively examine the properties for their properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you would need to do something similar to this:

***(untested)***

```
List<PropertyInfo> GetPropertiesRecursive(Type type)
{
    var properties = new List<PropertyInfo>
    foreach(var propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
    {
        properties.Add(propertyInfo);
        if(!propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsValueType)
        {
            properties.AddRange(GetPropertiesRecursive(propertyInfo.PropertyType));
        }
    }
    return properties;
}
```

Note that value types can have properties too.